# How many permutations in $S_8$ commute with $(1\,2\,3)(4\,5\,6)(7\,8)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

How many permutations $f\in S_8$ exist that satisfy $g = (1\,2\,3)(4\,5\,6)(7\,8)$ we have $fg = gf$ ?

Comment: any idea for this problem ?

Comment: How did u proceed?Show your contribution for this question

Comment: See Q.8 here: https://www.google.co.in/url?q=http://math.boisestate.edu/~holmes/math387/M387test3review.pdf&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiau4ONhLvXAhXHtI8KHa8uDVoQFggLMAA&usg=AOvVaw2ToZplEHb_q2KMzGrviG_I

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 3):

When you conjugate a permutation by $\sigma$, you get a permutation with the same cycle structure where $\sigma$ has acted on all the set elements. That is $$\sigma(123)(456)(78)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(1)\sigma(2)\sigma(3))\;(\sigma(4)\sigma(5)\sigma(6))\;(\sigma(7)\sigma(8))$$

So you need: $$(78)=(\sigma(7)\sigma(8))$$

And you need: $$(123)(456)=(\sigma(1)\sigma(2)\sigma(3))\;(\sigma(4)\sigma(5)\sigma(6))$$

I'll leave it to you to count how many options this makes for $\sigma$. Note cycles can equal each other without being written in the same way, and the same is true of products of cycles. (Since you didn't post anything you've tried, I am assuming this is enough of a hint to help.)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are familiar with the following concepts and results: The centraliser of an element, the conjugacy class of an element, the orbit-stabiliser theorem and the fact that permutations of the same cycle-type are conjugate in $S_n$.

You are looking for the size of the centraliser of $\sigma=(123)(456)(78)$ in $S_8$, $C(\sigma)$. By the orbit-stabiliser theorem, $|C(\sigma)|\times|\text{ccl}(\sigma)|=|S_8|$, where $\text{ccl}(\sigma)$ is the conjugacy class of $\sigma$.

Since the conjugacy class of a permutation in $S_n$ is always the set of all permutations of same cycle type, i.e. $(3)(3)(2)$, you need to find the number of permutations of that type. I reckon it's

$$\frac{1}{2}\Bigg(\frac{1}{3}\frac{8!}{5!}\Bigg)\Bigg(\frac{1}{3}\frac{5!}{2!}\Bigg)=1120\ ,$$

where the $\dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{8!}{5!}$ counts how many ways we can choose the first $3$-cycle, the $\dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{5!}{2!}$ counts how many ways we can choose the second $3$-cycle from the remaining numbers, and the $\dfrac{1}{2}$ is to adjust for over counting.

So, the final answer should be $$\frac{|S_8|}{|\text{ccl}(\sigma)|}=\frac{8!}{1120}=36.$$